# "Non-void function does not return a value in all control paths" error

Tags: c, if-statement, return-value

Whenever I am using `int` for returning multiple values to the main, I am getting this error.

```
int search(int key, struct node *temp)
{
      if(temp == NULL)
      return 0;
      else if(temp -> data == key)
      return 1;
      else if(key < temp -> data)
      search(key,temp -> left);
      else
      search(key,temp -> right);
}
```

Comment: what returns if `key < temp -> data`? Change those to `return search(key,temp -> left);` and `return search(key,temp -> right);`

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `temp -> data` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `temp->data`.

Comment: The compiler error is actually pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return something from all paths.  Simple calling `search()` does not cause its return value to be returned from within `search()`.

```
int search(int key, const struct node *temp) {
  if (temp == NULL) return 0;
  if (temp->data == key) return 1;
  if (key < temp->data) return search(key, temp->left); // return added. 
  return search(key, temp->right);                      // return added.
}
```

---

Also:

- Unneeded `else`s removed.
- Use `const struct node *temp` as `temp` referenced data is never changed.
- Other simplifications exist.